# An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected when comparing close and vwap

Tags: pine-script

When trying this code:

```
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(close > ta.vwap(hlc3) ? strategy.direction.long : strategy.direction.short)
```

I get this error:

> An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected

It happens from this:

```
close > ta.vwap(hlc3)
```

I am just trying to say that it should return true if the close is above vwap. What am I doing wrong here?

Sorry I'm new to pine and this is my first script.

Answer (score 1):

`simple string` means the variable's value should never change during the execution of the script.

You are passing your parameter with the ternary operator so its return value can change.

Comment: It's so incredibly limited, why on earth was Pinescript engineered in a way that someone cannot, for example, change the width of a line based on a dynamic value. It's mind numbing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

These things have always been achievable by using your own self created functions. For example alertconditon() can't use Series Strings (such as str.tostring(dynamic_float)) for the message parameter.

This is how this can be circumvented,

```html
newShortEntryAlertMessage(_message) =>
string(_message)

newLongEntryAlertMessage( _message) =>   
string(_message)

alertcondition(na(pivothighCondition) and trend == 0 and ta.crossunder(low, short_62_fib_level),"Watch For Short(Sell) Entry", newLongAlert("Look For Short(Sell) Entry, Entry Price: " + str.tostring(short_62_fib_level) + ", Shares: " + str.tostring(short_position_shares) + "(" + str.tostring(short_position_size_in_lots) + "), T/P: " + str.tostring(short_position_tp) + ", S/L: " + str.tostring(short_position_sl)))

alertcondition(na(pivotLowCondition) and trend == 1 and ta.crossunder(high, long_62_fib_level), "Watch For Long(Buy) Entry", newShortAlert("Look For Short(Sell) Entry, Entry Price: " + str.tostring(long_62_fib_level) + ", Shares: " + str.tostring(position_shares) + "(" + str.tostring(position_size_in_lots) + "), T/P: " + str.tostring(long_position_tp) + ", S/L: " + str.tostring(long_position_tp)))
```